# Codes that maximize average minimum distance from any tuple?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147382/). I'd wish to know about binary codes that seek to maximize, not the distance from each codeword to the nearest codeword, but the average distance from any vector ($n-$tuple) to the nearest codeword (or if both things are somewhat equivalent).

More in detail: Let $T=\{0,1\}^n$ be the set of all $n-$binary tuples. Let's call $C \subset T $ , with $|C|=M<2^n$, a "codebook" (with each element being a "codeword").

Let $$d_m^C=\min_{c_i, c_j \in C} d(c_i,c_j)\tag1$$ where $d()$ is the Hamming distance.

In the theory of linear error correcting codes, one clasically wants to design a $(n,k)$ code (with $M=2^k$ and $C$ being a vector subspace) which has a big $d_m^C$.

One could also be interested in the average distance from a each codeword to the nearest different codeword $$d^C_a= \frac{1}{M}\sum_{c_i \in C} \min_{c_j \in C,j \ne i} d(c_i,c_j) \tag2$$

... but for a linear code, $d^C_a=d^C_m$, because all terms inside the sum are equal.

Now suppose we are interested in computing the average distance to the nearest codeword, not from another codeword, but from each of the $2^n$ tuples:

$$d^T_a= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{x_i \in T} \min_{c_j \in C} d(x_i,c_j) \tag3$$

Again, we wish to design a $C$ (linear or not) that attains a big $d^T_a$, that is, that covers as evenly as possible (in this sense) the whole space.

Has this been studied? Some bounds or asymptotics?
In particular: are the usual codes, designed for high $d^C_a$, expected to perform well also with regards to $d^T_a$? Some preliminary (mostly numerical) work of mine (for the other question) seems to suggest that a random code performs better than a (say) BCH code, which surprised me a bit. Also, it would seem that there is a computable asymptotical value, and that the random code attains it.

I'd appreciate any pointers or answer.

Comment: Undoubtedly you have heard of *the covering radius* of a code, where we study the maximum instead of the average. IIRC for BCH codes the covering radius $\rho$ is surprisingly often given by the so called *supercode lemma*: if for two linear codes $C\subset C'$ and $d_{min}(C')<d_{min}(C)$ then the covering radius of $C$ is bounded from below by $d_{min}(C')$. The proof is trivial: pick a minimum weight word of $C'$ as $x$.

Comment: In the case of a linear code you question can be answered from a census of weight distribution of coset leaders. I don't have a strong intuition about whether the highest weight coset leaders dominate or not, but I guess they do to some extent. If you had asked me about this 20 years ago I would have been able to recite that census for the Reed-Muller codes $R(2,5)$  - I needed it for some $\Bbb{Z}_4$-code stuff. It will have to wait more, and I'm not entirely sure how relevant that is to your question (scratches head and sips more fine Caol Ila).